# Hive Sub query not supporting

Tags: hive, hiveql, greenplum

we are migrating greenplum to hive and below code creating issues for sub query not supported  by hive. please help me.

converted hive:

```
select concat_ws(';', max(concat_str)) 
FROM (
SELECT collect_list(Display_String) over (order by data_day ) concat_str 
FROM 
(select data_day, sum(revenue)/1000000.00 as revenue,data_day||' '||trim(regexp_replace(sum(revenue), '(?!^)(\\d\\d\\d(?=(\\d\\d\\d)*\\b))', ',$1')) as Display_String 
from(select case when data_date = current_date  then 'D:' when data_date = date_sub(current_date,1) then ' D-01:'
when data_date = date_sub(current_date,2) then ' D-02:'
when data_date = date_sub(current_date,7) then ' D-07:'
when data_date = date_sub(current_date,28) then ' D-28:'
 end data_day, revenue/1000000.00 revenue
from test.tablename
where data_date between date_sub(current_date,28) and current_date and 
hour <=(Select hour from ( select row_number() over(order by hour desc) iRowsID, 
hour from test.tablename where data_date = current_date and  type = 'UVC')tbl1
where irowsid = 2) and type in( 'UVC')
order by 1 desc) a
group by 1) aa ) concat_qry
```

old Greenplum code

```
select string_agg(Display_String, ';' order by data_day )
from
(
select data_day, 
sum(revenue)/1000000.00 as revenue,
data_day||' '||trim(to_char(sum(revenue),'9,999,999,999')) as Display_String 
from(
select case when data_date = current_date  then 'D:'
when data_date = current_date - 1 then ' D-01:'
when data_date = current_date - 2 then ' D-02:'
when data_date = current_date - 7 then ' D-07:'
when data_date = current_date - 28 then ' D-28:'
 end data_day, revenue/1000000.00 revenue
from test.tablename
where data_date between current_date - 28 and current_date and 
hour <=(Select hour from ( select row_number() over(order by hour desc) iRowsID, 
hour from test.tablename where data_date = current_date and  type = 'UVC')tbl1
where irowsid = 2) and type in( 'UVC')
order by 1 desc) a
group by 1)aa;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you pls try this ?

I did a left join instead of subquery. I couldn't check because i dont have necessary tables. pls let me know if you see any issues.

```
select concat_ws(';', max(concat_str)) 
FROM (
SELECT collect_list(Display_String) over (order by data_day ) concat_str 
FROM 
(select data_day, sum(revenue)/1000000.00 as revenue,data_day||' '||trim(regexp_replace(sum(revenue), '(?!^)(\\d\\d\\d(?=(\\d\\d\\d)*\\b))', ',$1')) as Display_String 
from(select case when data_date = current_date  then 'D:' when data_date = date_sub(current_date,1) then ' D-01:'
when data_date = date_sub(current_date,2) then ' D-02:'
when data_date = date_sub(current_date,7) then ' D-07:'
when data_date = date_sub(current_date,28) then ' D-28:'
 end data_day, revenue/1000000.00 revenue
from test.tablename
left join (Select hour hour_subq  from ( select row_number() over(order by hour desc) iRowsID, 
hour from test.tablename where data_date = current_date and  type = 'UVC')tbl1
where irowsid = 2)  rs ON hour <= rs.hour_subq  
where data_date between date_sub(current_date,28) and current_date 
and type in( 'UVC')
 ) a
group by 1) aa ) concat_qry
```

Comment: column reference "hour" is ambiguous¶  -- error

Comment: could you pls try new sql? i aliased it inside subquery.

Comment: left join (Select hour from ( select row_number() over(order by hour desc) iRowsID, 
hour from playground_mkt1.rpt_hourly_sub_sms where data_date = current_date and  type = 'UVC') tbl1
where irowsid = 2)  rs ON hour <= rs.hour

Comment: where exactly i have to give alise

Comment: tbl1.hour <= rs.hour after use alise and issues resolve but throwing some other issues..like    SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "tbl1"¶  Position: 883

Comment: Not 100% sure about your sql.can you pls post it in your question?

Comment: my issues resolved, thanks so much